# Turning this vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to create this in vanilla JS, granted jQuery was used. I wanted to use lean JS. The code below just gave quick results fast. However for build, I would like it leaner.

Several annoying factors, multiple child descendants, unknown classes all and have to be inside a loop.

```js
$('.nav__adv').each(function(){

 var $el = $(this),
  $no_advert = $('.main_ad_container div a div div', $el);

 $el.filter(function() {
     return $.trim($no_advert.text()) === "Advertise Here";
 }).css("display", "none").remove();

});
```

Any direction / help / guidance?

Comment: Would you call converting a working piece of code that uses a (well known, heavily tested) library to the same code without a library using 3x lines of unvarified code leaner? (I wouldn't). Leason to be learned: don't fix what isn't broken. Only optimize when you have performance issues

Comment: `$el.filter` seems pointless here given that `$el` is only ever going to refer to one element. If you just wrapped it in an `if` check for the advert test, it'd do the same thing

Comment: @Amit you do have a fair point, while I don't like leaning on libraries to much. jQuery is an exception. I just think its good to go vanilla where possible. Yes it is 3 lines, but I wanted to know what the community thought. If I can take out the middle man (jQuery) I will. But a few lines of code does seem tempting over a long code block.

Comment: This is too broad. You're, essentially, asking how to rewrite 8 different functions. Try focusing on one problem at a time.

Comment: @Quentin while you are correct, I want to keep my site lean using SCSS and PHP I want the leanest JS I can. I guess it seems trivial but I am keen to keen to get best from what I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using plain Javascript. Note that the advantage to using jQuery is that it will work cross browser.

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".nav__adv"), function(el) {
    var no_advert = el.querySelector(".main_ad_container div a div div");
    if(no_advert && no_advert.textContent.trim() === "Advertise Here") {
        el.parentElement.removeChild(el);
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="nav__adv">
    <div class="main_ad_container">
        <div>
            <a>
                <div>
                    <div>Advertise Here</div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="nav__adv">
    <div class="main_ad_container">
        <div>
            <a>
                <div>
                    <div>Leave Untouched</div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want cross-browser support in vanilla JS, this gets slightly more complicated.

Comment: Are you hinting at IE8 problems @RGraham?

Comment: @Neil Kind of. `querySelector` should be fine in IE8 as it's just simple selectors. `forEach` however will only work in IE9+ and even, only outside of strict mode. Replace the `forEach` with a standard `for` loop and it should work in IE8+

Comment: You missed a few spots :-) (for example, trim)

Comment: @Amit Thanks, added `trim()` - anything else missing?

Comment: @RGraham using less code, I get the same desired output. On reflection the code seems easier than the jQuery. I am interested to see what jsPerf shows on the difference.

Comment: @Neil - pay attention to details. This is less code, but significantly less functionality. A) It's not as compatible as the jQuery code. B) Your jQuery code does many "redundant" things due to the specific case (Such as RGraham's comment regarding `$.filter`). C) As a POC for my first comment, your `$no_advert` object can contain a list of element (depending on HTML structure), and `text()` will return the concatenation of all those element's text nodes. This solution only takes the text node from the FIRST element. It might make a difference, again, depending on use case - but hard to notice.

Answer (score 1):

Consider writing same code in js something like this. Although you don't have to write it as jQuery simplifies it with better and short syntax.

```js
var no_advert = document.querySelectorAll('.nav__adv .main_ad_container div a div div');

var el2hide = Array.prototype.filter.call(no_advert, function(elem) {
  return elem.textContent.trim() === "Advertise Here";
});

Array.prototype.map.call(el2hide, function(_this){ _this.remove(); });
```

```html
<div class="nav__adv">
  <div class="main_ad_container">
    <div>
      <a>
        <div>
          <div>Advertise Here</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="nav__adv">
  <div class="main_ad_container">
    <div>
      <a>
        <div>
          <div>Leave Untouched</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Yoshi thanks i guess that should be `nav_adv` instead of `this`. Although i mostly write code in jQuery.

Comment: And `nav_adv` won't have a `filter` method.

Comment: @RGraham yes i just never used it in plain js though, just gone through the documentations and used your html structure.

Comment: @Yoshi now i got it what you were trying to say. i have gone to the docs and found that `Array.prototype.filter.call()` should be used, i thought `.filter() and .map()` can be used for DOM nodes collections but not.

Comment: @Jai On the right track now. But the original code removes the `nav__adv` element, not just the div which contains the advert text. Also [remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) needs a polyfill to work on IE